# Want to get customers for each client from a duplicate list in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a project in Laravel with different users on the same table I differentiate them with their roles: user, pharma. Where the pharma sells products and the user is the buyer. but right now I want to get the customers for each client. These are the database tables :

**products**
id
user_id // (which is the foreign Key referencing the user's table: role=pharma)
name
amount

**orders**
id
user_id // (which is the foreign Key referencing the user's table: role=user)
product_id // ((which is the foreign Key referencing the product table)
name
amount

**users**
id
name
address

I try using the Laravel hasManyThroungh relationship through the product table to get the users
that ordered the client's product but I got all the orders. I just want to select the user
once but now I get the orders list of users who buy from the client. I need help selecting the user
from the duplicated list.

Comment: could you please post some code, that we can actually adjust? it's hard to just see words explaining what's happening without the actual code.

Comment: I suggest you split your "users" table in two distinct tables : 1 for customers, 1 for pharma sellers. Roles are mostly used for permissions/security uses, using it to distinguish two types of users is quite confusing in my opinion. So that your Orders table could have 2 foreign key columns to get your entities : `customer_id` and `seller_id`

Answer (score -1):

1. `group by user_id`
2. `foreach`
3. from user model relation ship to get?